# What is the C++ equivalent for the CRT?

Tags: c++, c, windows

I am new to C++, but I have worked with C before.

A program written in C must be linked with the CRT (in Windows, it is the file `libcmt.lib`) which contains the C functions (for example: `printf()`).

But I am wondering, is there such a thing as "C++RT" (as opposed to CRT), I mean where are the C++ functions and classes (for example: `std::ofstream`) stored.

And I have another question, if I used some C functions (for example: `printf()`), will my C++ program be linked with both the CRT and the "C++RT", or does the "C++RT" contains the CRT?

Comment: I recall C linking with [CRT](https://marketplacecdn.yoyogames.com/images/assets/3060/screenshots/8173_original.gif?1449578408)s even before windows ;-)

Comment: @chux is this a soap foam? o_O

Comment: Lots of standard C++ library code is stored in the headers.  But yes, you'll link libcpmt*.lib for non-templated code and template specializations.

Comment: @chux _I recall C linking with CRTs even before windows ;-)_ I remember even on the system with no CRT terminals :)

Comment: No, there is no inherent requirement of the C or C++ language that programs must be explicitly linked with a runtime library.  Many implementations of each language provide part or all of the appropriate standard library automatically when they compile a program; others, such as Microsoft's, do not.  The point is that you're asking about a particular implementation, not C or C++ in general.

Answer (score 21):

This depends on an exact implementation of [C++ standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library)  you are using.

[GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) ships with [libstdc++](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/) and your program is automatically linked against `libstdc++*.so*` or `libstdc++*.dll*` (filename may vary depending on distribution, build options and version used)

[Clang/LLVM](https://clang.llvm.org/) ships with [libc++](https://libcxx.llvm.org/) and `libc++*.so*` on Linux and OS X, but uses Visual C++ library on Windows.

[Microsoft Visual C++](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/cplusplus/) links against one of the `libcp*.lib` or `mscp*.lib` (and associated `.dll`) depending on configuration ([link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/154419/frequently-asked-questions-about-the-standard-c-library)).

Note that it is often possible to use non-default Standard library implementation. For example Clang can use either libstdc++ or libc++ on Linux. [Intel compiler](https://software.intel.com/en-us/c-compilers) uses Microsoft library on Windows and libstdc++ on Linux. There are (were) also implementations that are not associated with a particular compiler, like [STLport](http://stlport.sourceforge.net).